# Overwhelming testdox output when using data providers (with big number of data sets)

Tags: php, phpunit

We use dataproviders with a big number of data sets in our unit tests. For each data set PHPUnit prints a line in the testdox output. In our case this is overwhelming and makes the testdox output very hard to read and therefore useless.

I could not find a configuration setting or annotation that would let PHPUnit print only one line per test (regardless of the number of data sets the dataprovider returns) in the testdox output.

Is there a way that would let PHPUnit print only one line per test (regardless of the number of data sets the dataprovider returns) in the testdox output?

We use PHPUnit 8.4.1 and PHP 7.2.20.

--- Edited: Add example ---

This is a snippet of our current Testdox output:

```
 ...
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 805
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 806
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 807
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 808
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 809
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 810
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 811
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 812
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 813
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 814
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 815
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable aktivkonto an aufwandkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable aktivkonto an ertragkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable kundenkonto an aktivkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable kundenkonto an ertragkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable lieferantenkonto an aufwandkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 0
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 1
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 2
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 3
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 4
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 5
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 6
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 7
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 8
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 9
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 10
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records with data set 11
 ...
```

This could be a more condensed output e.g. if no data set would let a test fail:

```
 ...
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the account for all appropriate accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable aktivkonto an aufwandkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable aktivkonto an ertragkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable kundenkonto an aktivkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable kundenkonto an ertragkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the net amount to be used for the contra account for taxable lieferantenkonto an aufwandkonto accounting records
 ✔ Returns the cross amount to be used for the contra account for all appropriate accounting records
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such setting. And I do not think that it would be useful to add. You may want to look into the `@testdox` annotation and the possibility to use variables there (from data provider parameters) to produce more useful output.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. The `@testdox` annotation will not help because it is the very high number of output lines (not the wording) that make the Testdox output unclear. At the moment it is not usable for the product owner. I added an example to my question that shows a snippet of the Testdox output.

Comment: Please open a [Feature Request](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/new?labels=enhancement&template=FEATURE_REQUEST.md) issue on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks! https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3900